# Django "order_by " excluding the first items

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have this model, and I need to reset or `Purchased.bought_today` every day automatically at 00:00.

models.py

```
class Purchased(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_purchased = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 
    purchased_today = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I thought of resetting it whenever I login, with a signal.

but not found.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Purchased(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_purchased = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 
    purchased_today = models.IntegerField(default=0)


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def purchased_today_login(request, **kwargs):
today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
if purchased.last_purchased.date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") != today:
       purchased_today = 0
       subscription.save() 
       user_logged_in.connect(purchased_today_login)
```

If it worked it would be very good.

How can I do that?

Comment: The items bought today should be retrieved by the query (`filter(...)`) and not being filtered in Python code and set manually.

Comment: But I need use the signal.